# How can i retrieve a subrecord from mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a db that looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50525e55467f67da3f8baf06"),
    "client" : "client1" 
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("505262f0deed32a758410b1c"),
    "client" : "client2" 
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5052fe0a37083fd981616589"),
    "client" : "client3",
    "products" : [
        {"name" : "product1"},
        {"name" : "product2"}
    ]
}
```

How can i retrieve the product list of client3 without retrieving the client3 record ?
The output should look like this :

```
[
    {"name" : "product1"},
    {"name" : "product2"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can completely exclude the client3 record as the products are part of this record, but you can select **just** the `products` field like this:

```
db.<dbname>.find({ 'client' : 'client3' }, { 'products' : 1, '_id' : 0 })
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have another question :

Comment: I can't try it right now, but shouldn't { products : 1, _id: 0 } suppress the _id field?

Answer (score 0):

Also - if you want to get just the matching subrecord - see here

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

you use the $ operator in the project portion of find to specify the n'th subrecord where that is the first to match your query.